# Reducing execution time of an HTML parsing script

Tags: php, performance, web-scraping

The script is intended to return an array with texts containing specific words in English and the equivalent texts in Polish from EUR-Lex - a website with EU documents.

The script downloads the page which address is specified by the passed variable. Then [this page](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search.html?qid=1436957054496&text=%22event%20of%20default%22&scope=EURLEX&type=quick&lang=en) is parsed using regular expressions for the document codes. This code are then used to access [another page](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN-PL/TXT/?qid=1436957054496&uri=CELEX:32013R0575&from=EN). This page is then parsed for elements contained within `<tr>` tags, which, if their content contains words from the variable (checked with a regular expression), are saved in an array.

For variables containing 1-2 words the script works fairly well; not so well for more. I got complaints from my free hosting provider (hostinger.in) that the script uses too much resources. I have other scripts run before that script, but not simultaneously, so I don't if they contribute to the problem.

```
<?php
//test variables
//$var1 = 'board_of_directors';
//$var1 = 'affidavit';
$var1 = 'event_of_default';
$var1 = explode("_", $var1);
$words = implode(" ",$var1);
if (count($var1) >= 2) {
    $var1 = implode("%20",$var1);
} else {
    $var1 = implode("%",$var1);
}
$var1 = "\""."$var1"."\"";
$html = file_get_contents("http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search.html?qid=1&text=$var1&scope=EURLEX&type=quick&lang=en");
preg_match_all('/CELEX:(\w+)&/si', $html, $matches2);
$result = array_unique($matches2[1]);
$result2 = file_get_contents("http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN-PL/TXT/?uri=CELEX:$result[0]&from=EN");
$dom = new domDocument; 
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($result2); 
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$return_array = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length - 1; $i++) {
    $text1 = $items->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->textContent;
    if (preg_match('/' . $words . '/i', $text1)) {
        $text2 = $items->item($i)->childNodes->item(1)->textContent;
        array_push($return_array, $text1);
        array_push($return_array, $text2);
    }
}
echo json_encode($return_array);

?>
```

Comment: Reviewing the HTML pages you gave as example, I guess that the main issue should come from looping `preg_match`on `<tr>`s of the 2nd one, rather than the unique `preg_match_all` on the 1st one. That said, I feel puzzled: since this 2nd HTML page is pretty heavy, anyway it might take time to analyze it **whatever the number of involved words**. So I"m surprised that it works fairly well for only 1 or 2 words.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can do to improve here:

- Use `curl` instead of `get_file_contents`, it speeds the document retrieval up so much.
- The following could be converted to a ternary statement:

> ```
> if (count($var1) >= 2) {
>     $var1 = implode("%20",$var1);
> } else {
>     $var1 = implode("%",$var1);
> }
> ```

Notice that the condition is reversed:

```
$var1 = implode('%' + (!count($var1) >= 2 ?: "20"), $var1);
```

- You shouldn't be joining strings like this: `"\""."$var1"."\""`:

Do this instead: `"\"{$var1}\""` (see that the variable is wrapped in curly braces)

- Don't `array_push`, use the `$array[]` notation instead.

  ```
  $return_array[] = $text1;
  $return_array[] = $text2;
  ```